# Creating a button using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have attached part of the code I'm modifying. I would like to create a button using Tkinter such that , based on the option I sect using the button (A or B), I would like to resize the image in the line `cv_image = image[:,:,:]`.

What is the best way to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
class image_converter:

  def __init__(self):
    print 'show window'
    cv2.namedWindow("Image window", 1)
    print 'start bridge and subscribe'
    self.bridge = CvBridge()
    print Image
    self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/MDS_CamServer/camera/image",Image,self.callback)
    self.save = False;
    self.count=0;
    self.X=np.array([[]]);
    self.y=np.array([[]]);
    self.X_new=np.array([[]]);
    self.y_new=np.array([[]]);

  def callback(self,data):
    try:
      image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError, e:
      print e

    cv_image = image[:,:,:];


def main(args):
  ic = image_converter()
  rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
  try:
    rospy.spin()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Shutting down"
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show a "Button A" or a "Button B". Your code includes a package named "rospy" - is that necessary to duplicate the problem? What do you mean by "resize"? Make the image twice as big? Half as big? Some random factor bigger or smaller?

Comment: I have included snippet of the code to give an idea about the structure of the code. So please ignore lines that are not relevant ( eg rospy). I would like to create the button A or B ( it is not in the code and this is what I need help with). Based on the choice of A or B, I would like  to have cv_image=image[:,:,:] or image[10:120,30:130,:] (basically crop the image.

Comment: If lines of code aren't relevant, please don't include them. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

you should create a radio button to select which option user wants to choose A or B and then on choosing redirect the user to specific width

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code snippet

```
self.v1 = IntVar()
Label(master, text="""resize the image in the line with """,justify = LEFT, padx = 20).pack()
Radiobutton(master, text="A",padx = 20, variable=self.v1, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="B", padx = 20, variable=self.v1, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
if self.v2.get() == 1:
   Imgwidth = 100 #specify it as per A
else:
   Imgwidth = 200 #specify it as per B
Imgheight = 100#just specify or use original 
image = Image.open(Image_Location)
image = image.resize((Imgheight, Imgwidth), Image.ANTIALIAS) #The (250, 250) is (height, width)
self.pw.pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

Comment: As written, this won't work. You ate getting the value of the radiobutton before the user has a chance to click on one of them.